# Assigning data to each point in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have plotted circles for the CX and CY points from database
I put on click event on each of these points.
On click works but the circles take the last index only.
the index doesnt change according to the point
The data is in tempdata from database
Also when i checked in browser console, "d" in the function shows attributes of the image on which the circles are plotted and not the attributes of circle.

```
var removeRect = function(idCircle){
         //d3.selectAll('g #'+id).remove();
    console.log("index : " + JSON.stringify(idCircle));
 };     

for(var i=0; i< tempdata.length; i++)
    {
        var name = "circle"+i;

        d3.select("#floor svg")
            .append("svg:circle")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("fill", "green")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("cx", tempdata[i].CX)
            .attr("cy", tempdata[i].CY)
            .attr("idCircle",name)
            //.attr('onclick',"removeRect('circle_"+name+"')")
            //.on("click", removeRect(name))
             .on("click", function(d,index){
                console.log("d" + JSON.stringify(d));
                removeRect(name);
            })          

        hashtemp[i]="#"+i;

/*      d3.select(hashtemp[i])
            .on("click", function(d,index) {
                console.log("index : " + JSON.stringify(d));
            var summarydata = "";
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    $scope.selected_marker = tempdata[index];
                    console.log(tempdata[index]);
                    }
                ) */

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing things the "D3 way". D3 can bind arbitrary data to arbitrary elements, so no loops are required. Just tell d3 that you want to bind this array of data to these elements (which may or may not exist), and then assign attributes based on the current data and index.

```
d3.select("#floor svg").selectAll('circle')
    .data(tempdata).enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", (d,i)=>tempdata[i].CX)
        .attr("cy", (d,i)=>tempdata[i].CY)
        .attr("idCircle",(d,i)=>'circle'+i)
        //.attr('onclick',"removeRect('circle_"+name+"')")
        //.on("click", removeRect(name))
         .on("click", function(d,index){
            console.log("d" + JSON.stringify(d));
            removeRect(name);
        })
```

EDIT: Forgot to put `selectAll('circle')`

Comment: If I have to add image instead of circle, I ll have to add image in the place of circle. and then the link in next attr. But that didnt work. I had also assigned height & width attribute

Comment: My data is in tempdata variable and then i m using for loop for plotting those point and respective data. how can I point them if I dont use the loop? If I remove for loop, it doesnt plot the given points. it automatically taking the points with x=0 and y=0 and plotting all points at 0,0 point

Comment: Like i said, you don't use loops when using D3. Either read up on D3 or make me a working jsfiddle.